# JqueryMobile Asp:Dropdownlist AutoPostback

Tags: asp.net

I have a asp:DropDownList element in my mobile aspx page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="formulationSelect" AutoPostBack ="true" EnableViewState =" true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="languageSelect" AutoPostBack ="true"   EnableViewState =" true" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

i have exactly same code on my normal aspx page (this works fine). I am wanting it so that when a different value is selected it performs a postback (no method is needing to be fired) but when it postbacks, the code then uses the new selected value in the dropdown box to load new objects.

Problem is when i select the value no postback is performed, and i get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
__doPostBack
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, did you ever manage to solve it?

Comment: yeah i did actually... in the url you post back to, make sure it as the tag rel="external" and it will work